# Как реализовать удаление объекта по введённому номеру

Tags: c++

```
// Hero's Inventory
//arrays
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>    
#include <vector>       

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    const int MAX_ITEMS = 10;
    string inventory[MAX_ITEMS];

    int numItems = 0;
    inventory[numItems++] = "sword";
    inventory[numItems++] = "armor";
    inventory[numItems++] = "shield";


    cout << "Your items:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; ++i)
    {
        cout << inventory[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "\nYou trade your sword for a battle axe.";
    inventory[0] = "battle axe";
    cout << "Your items:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; ++i)
        cout << inventory[i] << endl;
    cout << "\nThe item name '" << inventory[0] << "' has ";
    cout << inventory[0].size() << " letters in it.\n";
    cout << "\nYou find a healing potion.";
    if (numItems < MAX_ITEMS)
        inventory[numItems++] = "healing potion";
    else
        cout << "You have too many items and can't carry another";

    while (true)
    {
        string s;
        getline(cin, s);
        string toadd;
        if (s == "S") {
            toadd = "sword";
                cout << "В ваш инвентарь добавлен меч\n"; 
        }
        else if (s == "H") {
            toadd = "healing potion";
            cout << "В ваш инвентарь добавлена хилка\n";
        }
        else if (s == "A") {
            toadd = "armor";
            cout << "В ваш инвентарь добавлена броня\n";
        }
        else if (s == "D") {
            if (numItems == 0) 
            {
                cout << "You have no items in inventory!\n";
                
            }
            else {
             inventory[--numItems] = "";
                
                cout << "Из вашего инвентаря удалён предмет\n\n";
            }
            continue;

        }
        else {
            cout << "Input is not correct";
        }
        if (numItems < MAX_ITEMS)
            inventory[numItems++] = toadd;
        else
            cout << "You have too many items and can't carry another";
   
    }


    cout << "Your items:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; ++i)
        cout << inventory[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если номер соответствует последнему предмету в инвентаре, то просто удалить, использую уже готовую логику (только почините ее). Если нет - сдвинуть все элементы правее его на 1 единицу влево и уменьшить количество предметов. Например: `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]`, удаляем `c` -> `["a", "b", "d", "e", ""]`

Comment: 1. `if (numItems < MAX_ITEMS)` выйдет за пределы массива при `numItems = 9`. Эта переменная отражает не **количество**, а **индекс** последнего предмета. 2. `inventory[--numItems] = "";` удаляет **пред**последний элемент. Чтобы удалять последний - замените на `inventory[numItems--] = "";`